# OpenGl Z-Order Equivalent in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, formatting

I am trying to draw the arrows in this picture on top of the two parallel plates. In OpenGL I would just set the 4th coordinate the z-order to be closer. Any ideas how to draw them on top in mathematica?

[image: 3D]

```
R0 = .5;
Rl = 12;
Rw = 1;
or = {-0.5, 0, -0.}
ArrRad = 0.1;
ArrLen = 2;
(*vp=Options[Graphics3D,ViewPoint][[1,2]];*)
vp = {2.172860287784637`, -2.2696686904229137`, 1.2558989630867607`};
Graphics3D[{(*EdgeForm[Thickness[0.002]],*)
  (*Top Plate*)
  {Gray, Opacity[1],  Polygon[{{0, -Rw, R0}, {0, Rw, R0}, {Rl, Rw, R0}, {Rl, -Rw, R0}}]},
  (*Bottom Plate*)
  {Gray, Polygon[{{0, -Rw, -R0}, {0, Rw, -R0}, {Rl, Rw, -R0}, {Rl, -Rw, -R0}}]},
  (*Arrow E*)
  {Red, Arrow[ Tube[{or + {#, 0, 0}, or + {#, 0, ArrLen*Sin[(2 \[Pi])/Rl #]} }]] & /@ 
    Table[x, {x, 0, Rl, Rl/12}]},
  (*Arrow H*)
  {Green,  Arrow[Tube[{or + {#, 0, 0}, or + {#, ArrLen*Cos[(2 \[Pi])/Rl #], 0} }]] & /@ 
    Table[x, {x, 0, Rl, Rl/12}]}
  }, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ImageSize -> 400]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can influence the *z-buffer* of graphics directives directly so that they don't cover each other. One solution, if I understood your question correctly, would be to move the arrows in the direction of the view vector. First your code where I assign the image to `gr`:

```
R0 = .5;
Rl = 12;
Rw = 1;
or = {-0.5, 0, -0.};
ArrRad = 0.1;
ArrLen = 2;
vp = {2.172860287784637`, -2.2696686904229137`, 1.2558989630867607`};
gr = Graphics3D[{(*EdgeForm[Thickness[
    0.002]],*)(*Top Plate*){Gray, Opacity[1], 
     Polygon[{{0, -Rw, R0}, {0, Rw, R0}, {Rl, Rw, R0}, {Rl, -Rw, 
        R0}}]},(*Bottom Plate*){Gray, 
     Polygon[{{0, -Rw, -R0}, {0, Rw, -R0}, {Rl, 
        Rw, -R0}, {Rl, -Rw, -R0}}]},(*Arrow E*){Red, 
     Arrow[Tube[{or + {#, 0, 0}, 
          or + {#, 0, ArrLen*Sin[(2 \[Pi])/Rl #]}}]] & /@ 
      Table[x, {x, 0, Rl, Rl/12}]},(*Arrow H*){Green, 
     Arrow[Tube[{or + {#, 0, 0}, 
          or + {#, ArrLen*Cos[(2 \[Pi])/Rl #], 0}}]] & /@ 
      Table[x, {x, 0, Rl, Rl/12}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ImageSize -> 400];
```

And then you can try something like the following. Please note, that you can adjust the zoom (which is altered when moving the arrows) with the `ViewAngle` option:

```
moveAlong[pt_, v_, l_] := pt + Normalize[v]*l

Manipulate[
 gr /. Tube[{p1_, p2_}] :> 
   Tube[{moveAlong[p1, vp, l], moveAlong[p2, vp, l]}],
 {l, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: can you provide the full code, Its not quite working here

Comment: +1 interesting problem and solution. I wonder if setting Opacity for the plates would help. @AimForClarity

Comment: @halirutan  thanks :) i think what i missed is the ViewAngle Option.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov  Thanks :) i tried that but not the same effect